# Access JSON values within a foreach

Tags: php, json

I am trying to access various parts of a json request, a typical response is:

```
{
   "Overview" : {
      "firstresultposition" : 1,
      "totalresultsreturned" : 2,
      "linkpop" : "2",
      "domainpop" : "2",
      "netpop" : "1",
      "ippop" : "1"
   },
   "Results" : [
      {
         "Links" : [
            {
               "UrlTo" : "http://www.eclecticaartisans.com/",
               "Anchor" : "Eclectica Artisans' Shop",
               "nofollow" : "0"
            }
         ],
         "IP" : "64.14.78.39",
         "Index" : 1,
         "DomainRank" : "5",
         "UrlFrom" : "http://www.shoppernews.com/directory.html"
      },
      {
         "UrlFrom" : "http://shoppernews.com/directory.html",
         "DomainRank" : "4",
         "Index" : 2,
         "IP" : "64.14.78.39",
         "Links" : [
            {
               "UrlTo" : "http://www.eclecticaartisans.com/",
               "Anchor" : "Eclectica Artisans' Shop",
               "nofollow" : "0"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

What i'm trying to do is get 2 pieces of data in the 1 foreach loop rather than 2 this:

```
<?php
$returnSK = file_get_contents("REQUEST_URL");
$seoKicks = json_decode($returnSK, true);
print "<pre>"; print_r($returnSK); print "</pre>";
foreach ($seoKicks['Results'] as $key => $val2) {
    echo $val2['UrlFrom'];
    foreach ($val2['Links'] as $arr) {
        echo $arr['Anchor'];
    }
}
?>
```

The above code works fine, but i really need to access the "UrlFrom" and the "Anchor" values using the 1 foreach loop if possible (the 2 foreach's above is slightly more complicated when put into my live project when adding to the database) any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what are you trying to do with the Links data? If there will only be one all the time you could just access it by index without a loop other wise you need to iterate or map Links array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With one foreach,

```
foreach ($seoKicks['Results'] as $key => $val2) {
    echo $val2['UrlFrom'];
    echo $val2['Links'][0]['Anchor'];
}
```

Comment: There's no `$val2[0]`.

Comment: It should be `$val2['Links'][0]['Anchor']`

Comment: @Barmar Yesh you're right, I've edited it. Thankyou.

Comment: Thank you guys, that was it :)